# Accessing outer this in extension property

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-extension

I have function like this that works fine:

```
private fun <T : CSName> List<T>.toStringArray() = list<String>().apply {
    for (hasName in this@toStringArray) add(hasName.name)
}.toTypedArray()
```

I wanted to convert it to property syntax like this:

```
private val <T : CSName> List<T>.asStringArray get() = list<String>().apply {
    for (hasName in this@asStringArray) add(hasName.name)
}.toTypedArray()
```

But it doesn't compile. Android Studio even suggest this in autocompletion, but it's wrong. I am not sure where is the problem/bug. Android Studio auto completion is wrong ? Is this even possible in kotlin ?

Comment: BTW, `asStringArray` is not a good name.  `asXxx` methods usually return a _view_ of an object, one which reflects changes made to it (and vice versa, if mutable) — which this doesn't.

Comment: @gidds i don't agree and thanks good I don't have to discuss it with you ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should explicitly specify a type of the property:

```
private val <T : CSName> List<T>.asStringArray: Array<String>
    get() = list<String>().apply {
        for (hasName in this@asStringArray) add(hasName.name)
    }.toTypedArray()
```

BTW, the same result can be achieved with less code, using `map` function:

```
private val <T : CSName> List<T>.asStringArray get() = map { it.name }.toTypedArray()
```

Comment: Ok thanks. Editor could be little more friendly because I didn't write it wrong then.. Thanks for less code example too...

Comment: To name that function map is kind of wired for me... I use same and similarly named functions for obviously Map creation and helper functions and this is making my code less readable now...